# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when performing request to the server

Tags: ajax, rest

on my server it runs a RESTful web service:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{deviceId}/dashboard")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getDashboard(@PathParam("deviceId") int id){
        List<Integer> dataNachId = new ArrayList<>();


        dataNachId = allData.get(Integer.toString(id));

        if(dataNachId==null){
            return "No Data";
        }
        return "{data:"+dataNachId.toString()+"}";
    }
```

and I would like to retrieve the return data by calling ajax request to the server as follow (using jsfiddle):

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8085/WSDemo/webapi/data/1/dashboard',
    success: function() {
      console.log('success', data);
    }
  });
});
```

but what I saw on the console is an error with the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Try using `crossDomain: true`

Answer (score 0):

Just add dataype and crossdomain in the ajax request you are sending.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://localhost:8085/WSDemo/webapi/data/1/dashboard',
    success: function() {
      console.log('success', data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: hi thanks for your response, but then I got another error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement. Do you know why this happen? Thanks

Comment: can u copy/paste the screenshot of the error.. or line number? or try to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: I dont know why but sometime it happens, sometime not and now it disappear :( but anyway I still can not connect to the server although it still running, it means in the console log it not print the success function, and I test it by put the error check:  error: function() {
       console.log('error');
              } and it showed the 'error'